# NetBeans GlassFish 4.0. not starting

Tags: java, glassfish

I'm trying to load a demo project on a GlassFish Server (https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-intro.html). Something is wrong. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
Starting GlassFish Server 4.0
GlassFish Server 4.0 starting.
C:\Users\Paul\Documents\NetBeansProjects\jsfDemo\jsfDemo\build\web
Initializing...
deploy?DEFAULT=C:\Users\Paul\Documents\NetBeansProjects\jsfDemo\jsfDemo\build\web&name=jsfDemo&contextroot=/jsfDemo&force=true refusal on GlassFish Server 4.0 
 Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [jsfDemo] : Servlet [ParticipantPortImpl] and Servlet [CoordinatorPortImpl] have the same url pattern: [/WSAT11Service]. Related annotation information: annotation [@javax.jws.WebService(wsdlLocation=/wsdls/wsat11/wstx-wsat-1.1-wsdl-200702.wsdl, targetNamespace=http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-tx/wsat/2006/06, name=, endpointInterface=com.sun.xml.ws.tx.at.v11.types.CoordinatorPortType, portName=CoordinatorPort, serviceName=WSAT11Service)] on annotated element [class com.sun.xml.ws.tx.at.v11.endpoint.CoordinatorPortImpl] of type [TYPE]. Please see server.log for more details.
C:\Users\Paul\Documents\NetBeansProjects\jsfDemo\jsfDemo\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1040: The module won't develop.
Detailed data are given in the server protocol.
ASSEMBLY is COMPLETE WITH FAILURE (the general time: 1 minute 41 second)
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you didn't create a proper WAR.  Check your packaging.

Comment: https://www.java.net//forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/coordinatorportimpl-and-servlet-participantportimpl-have-same-pattern

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, later reallized I had embedded glassfish in my POM file without "provided" scope. Changed the scope of this dependency to "provided" and it resolved my pro